# Different browser behaviour for width of nested flexbox containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with getting identical behaviour for a flexbox layout in different browsers (nevermind browsers that don't support flexbox).

Here's the markup:

```
<!-- nested version -->
<div class="flex-container"> <!-- display: flex -->
  <div>
    <div class="flex-container inner"> <!-- display: flex -->
      <div class="auto-width">
        auto take up needed space
      </div>
      <div class="flex-width"> <!-- flex: 1 -->
        flex take up remaining space
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that IE11 behaves differently to Firefox and Chrome. I would expect that the width of the nested flexbox `flex-container.inner` will be unrestricted, since nowwhere do I set any width.

Here is a JSBin to illustrate the problem: http://jsbin.com/pabesaci/5. Example 3 is the problematic one which renders differently in IE.

Rendering in IE

[image: Rendering in IE]

Rendering in Chrome (FF is similar)

[image: Rendering in Chrome]

Is this a bug in IE?

Can you suggest other ways to achieve this layout?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://imgur.com/5aoFXm7)?

Comment: @MartinMetsalu well, not quite, the inner flex container should only grow as large as its children require (that was not clear from my screenshots, but that is the behaviour of FF and Chrome)

Comment: how about [now](http://imgur.com/0IL1jPO)?

Comment: If your not already using it, look into Normalize.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>My example:</p>

<div style="float:left; display:block; width: auto; border: solid 2px red; padding: 2px;">
  <div>
    <div style="float:left; display: block; border: solid 2px yellow; padding:2px;">
      <div style="float:left; display: block; border: solid 2px green;">
        auto take up needed space
      </div>
      <div class="" style="float:left; position:relative; display:block; border: solid 2px blue;">
       flex take up remaining space
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: he specifically says: "Can you suggest other ways to achieve this layout?"

Comment: Thank you, @MartinMetsalu. I'll accept this as the ansswer. I was hoping for a solution using flexbox, but this'll have to do, when browsers don't behave the same